# New white space when viewing questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There is some new white space on the sides of the page when viewing a question (it use to be the blue Arqade background).  This also happens in the Meta site:

[image: picture]

Is this a bug or intended now? I was able to reproduce in Chrome and Edge.

Comment: I was able to see this happen on other SE sites as well.  I looked on Meta.SE, and I'm not sure if [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304096/comments-and-answers-have-huge-right-margins-when-printed) is the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if an update was made, but the issue has seem to have been corrected. Arqade and other SE sites appear normal once again.